# Revealing Content with Silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight

I have a Silverlight 4 application. This application has a page with three radio buttons on it. By default, none of these radio buttons are chosen. However, when a user chooses one of the radio buttons, I want to reveal some content by sliding the remaining buttons down. For instance:

- option 1
- option 2
- option 3

*user clicks option 1*

- option 1

  - my content appears here. Items 2 and 3 would slide down.
- option 2
- option 3

*If the user clicks option 2, it would look like this:*

- option 1
- option 2

  - my content appears here. Item 3 would slide down. Item 1 is collapsed.
- option 3

Does anyone know how I can do this with Silverlight? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

you can put all the elements as visible, then bind the `Checked` property of the `RadioButton` controls to the `Visibility` property of the portions you want to be able to hide/show, and use a *value converter* to convert the Checked (bool) to Visibility.

example:

```
<StackPanel>
    <RadioButton Name="r1" Content="Radio1" GroupName="group1"/>
    <Grid Visibility="{Binding Checked, ElementName=r1, Converter={StaticResource boolToVisibilityConverter}">
        <TextBlock Text="Hidden until Radio1 is checked"/>
    </Grid>
    <RadioButton Content="Radio2" GroupName="group1"/>
    <RadioButton Content="Radio2" GroupName="group1"/>
</StackPanel>
```

Here is a boolToVisibilityConverter:

```
public class boolToVisibilityConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if(!(value is bool))
               throw new Exception("invalid type");
            return ((bool)value)? Visibility.Visible: Visibility.Collapsed;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            // Most of the time you are not handling bi-directional converts, but you need
            // to implement the contract of IValueCoverter fully regardless.
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your converter still returns a `bool`: you should convert it to a `Visibility` instead of inverting it.

Comment: I have corrected the code that "Nissan Fan" added for the converter.

Comment: In Silverlight 4, the binding property name is "IsChecked".

Answer (score 1):

if you have Silverlight toolkit installed, you will have access to a control called Accordion. It does exactly what you are looking for. :)

the toolkit
http://silverlight.codeplex.com/

the Accordion control video tutorial
http://www.silverlight.net/learn/videos/all/silverlight-toolkit-accordion-control/